# libx264 not found FFmpeg?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, nasm, msys

I am trying to make a build of ffmpeg with libx264 enabled. However when I run the following command in MSYS

```
./configure --prefix=ffmpeg/ --enable-gpl --enable-libx264
```

I get an error saying

```
ERROR: libx264 not found
```

I am using MSYS on windows 10. I also have installed NASM. Here is the config.log file

```
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.TRVJWfGe/test.c
    1   #include <stdint.h>
    2   #include <x264.h>
    3   #include <stdint.h>
    4   long check_x264_encoder_encode(void) { return (long) x264_encoder_encode; }
    5   int main(void) { int ret = 0;
    6    ret |= ((intptr_t)check_x264_encoder_encode) & 0xFFFF;
    7   return ret; }
END /tmp/ffconf.TRVJWfGe/test.c
gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x0700 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__printf__=__gnu_printf__ -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -std=c11 -fomit-frame-pointer -c -o /tmp/ffconf.TRVJWfGe/test.o /tmp/ffconf.TRVJWfGe/test.c
In file included from c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:46,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\stdint.h:9,
                 from C:/Users/pawel/AppData/Local/Temp/ffconf.TRVJWfGe/test.c:1:
c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:413:3: warning: #warning "Direct definition of __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO is deprecated." [-Wcpp]
  413 | # warning "Direct definition of __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO is deprecated."
      |   ^~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:414:10: note: #pragma message: See <_mingw.h> for preferred feature activation methods.
  414 | # pragma message "See <_mingw.h> for preferred feature activation methods."
      |          ^~~~~~~
C:/Users/pawel/AppData/Local/Temp/ffconf.TRVJWfGe/test.c:2:10: fatal error: x264.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <x264.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ERROR: libx264 not found
```

Could you tell me how to fix the error, or is there a prebuilt package with libx264 already inside?

Comment: You need to compile and install libx264 first. Ffmpeg does not come with it.

Comment: Could you tell me how to install it or a link to a page that could help me with that. It would be much appreciated (I am new to MSYS and make).

Comment: Just like any other library. git clone, make install.

Comment: I have installed x264 from https://github.com/mstorsjo/x264.git with configure --disable-asm as I dont have yasm and I still get the error that libx264 is not found.

Comment: `--disable-asm` is not recommended as it will negatively affect performance. [ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers](https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers) might be an easier method for you, or see [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile - Windows](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide#Windows). Or be lazy and just download `ffmpeg.exe` from [Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Comment: I have decided to just go the lazy way and used the pre-built version of ffmpeg for my c++ project. Thanks for the help :)